# iOS Configuration Profile Expiration

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, enterprise

We are building iOS OTA Enrollment system in our IT.
After reading Apple docs, i would not find reference how to set an expiration date on the Configuration Profile installed on the device.

My motivation is to create expiration date on profiles that i am going to install based on the device owner (they have to login before i install it)

Is there a way to control how long the Configuration Profile is valid for?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration Profile has 2 keys:

```
RemovalDate
DurationUntilRemoval
```

Which takes a date or duration in seconds respectively, which when satisfied, will remove the profile. But maybe that wasn't what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The Configuration Profile supports the key "PayloadExpirationDate".

You can set the expiration date in the profile, and after the expiration, a new button inside the profile will appear to update the profile manually.

You can see the documentation in the following link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

Also, the Apple documentation "Over-the-Air Profile Delivery Concepts" says

> Upon receiving the final encrypted profile, the device installs it. 
>   Reconfiguration occurs automatically if the profile expires or if
>   a VPN connection attempt fails.

However, I wasn't able to update the profile, not manually and not automatically.

Comment: There is a bug in iOS 8 (still present in 8.1) where OTA profile updating is failing.

Comment: Was this bug published? Do you have some more information? Thanks

Comment: Facing the same problem. Tried 1) setting the PayloadExpirationDate, 2) causing the VPN server connection to fail, and 3) causing the VPN authentication to fail. None of the above made the device pull the profile server for a new configuration profile. Was anyone able to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to control the expiration date.